# Ubuntu 18.04 Network card with two IP addresses

Tags: netplan

I would like to learn how to setup my network card with two IP addresses

I tried as bellow, but now

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
     enp0s3:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: [ 192.168.0.2/32, 172.16.0.2/16 ]
        gateway4: 192.168.0.1
        gateway4: 172.16.0.1
        nameservers:
              search: [usp.br]
              addresses: [ 192.168.0.100, 192.168.0.102 ]
        optional: true
```

Each IP has its own gateway....

Could you please help me how to it?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

There are often issues with having multiple gateways set for interfaces. Routing packets over to one and then the other may lead to confusion on the network, so you're often best served by having a single default gateway unless you really know what you are doing.

In short, you usually want only one

```
gateway4: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

line in your config.

If you must have multiple routes for the individual IPs of the interface, you can control exactly how they will behave by writing static routes (and setting the metric based on the priority of the addresses), like so:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
     enp0s3:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: [ 192.168.0.2/32, 172.16.0.2/16 ]
        nameservers:
              search: [usp.br]
              addresses: [ 192.168.0.100, 192.168.0.102 ]
        routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: 192.168.0.1
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: 172.168.0.1
```

You also don't need *optional: true*: it only stops delaying boot if the interface isn't coming up fast enough, which shouldn't be an issue given that you specific static addresses. Adding *optional: true* also has the side effect of not blocking for some targets in **systemd**, which might mean a server will not start all the services it should right away if these services need the network.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but...
It makes little sense to have 2 default gateways. Think about it:
If i do ping 8.8.8.8, what gateway should it use?

You CAN setup priority, if one line is slower/more expensive/only for backup/... 
If both have same priority, I suspect it will try to do round-robbin.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into exactly the same problem. I saw the answer here (from
Mathieu Trudel-Lapierre), but it doesn't really solve the problem. The netplan will issue an error that there are two default routes for one routing table. It's right to do so:

1. To add the `800` table in routing tables:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
   ```

   To add there a line in the end:

   ```
   800 second_ip
   ```
2. Your netplan configuration plan should be:

   ```
   network:
     version: 2
     renderer: NetworkManager
     ethernets:
        enp0s3:
           dhcp4: no
           dhcp6: no
           addresses: [ 192.168.0.2/32, 172.16.0.2/16 ]
           nameservers:
                 search: [usp.br]
                 addresses: [ 192.168.0.100, 192.168.0.102 ]
           routes:
               - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                 via: 192.168.0.1
               - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                 via: 172.16.0.1
                 table: 800
           routing-policy:
               - from: 172.16.0.2
                 table: 800
   ```

   It is important to note here that the first gateway (`192.168.0.1`) should be into the main table (that is, we do not specify `routes/table:`), and the second gateway go into the `800` table (`routes/table: 800`). And we have to use the `routing-policy` for the second IP address (`172.16.0.2`) - it is necessary that if packets come from this IP address, they will go exactly to the `800` table and will be sent to the second gateway (`172.16.0.1`).

   If you just run `ping 8.8.8.8`, then the server needs to understand from which IP address to send packets to it. In this case, it will search for the default route in the `main` table and find the gateway `192.168.0.1`, and it will understand from which IP address to send packets by default - from `192.168.0.2`. It is important that if there is no `default` route in the `main` table (for example, if I had defined the first default route in another table, for example `801`) - you will not be able to initiate packets from the server (for example `ping 8.8.8.8`) - the server will only be able to respond to packets that came to its IP addresses from outside.